# Network manager drops wired connection

Tags: 16.04, network-manager

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 on Lenovo E530. My network manager drops wired connection after few seconds. Wifi works fine. How this can be fixed?

My network cards:

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2230 (rev c4)
0c:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 07)
```

**Update #1**

After setting static IP address plugging in cable and ran command

```
sudo ethtool enp12s0
```

Result is:

```
Settings for enp12s0:
Supported ports: [ TP ]
Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                        1000baseT/Full 
Supported pause frame use: No
Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                        1000baseT/Full 
Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
Speed: 10Mb/s
Duplex: Full
Port: Twisted Pair
PHYAD: 0
Transceiver: internal
Auto-negotiation: on
MDI-X: Unknown
Supports Wake-on: pumbg
Wake-on: g
Current message level: 0x00000033 (51)
               drv probe ifdown ifup
Link detected: no
```

After unplug:

```
Settings for enp12s0:
Supported ports: [ TP ]
Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                        1000baseT/Full 
Supported pause frame use: No
Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                        1000baseT/Full 
Advertised pause frame use: No
Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
Speed: 100Mb/s
Duplex: Half
Port: Twisted Pair
PHYAD: 0
Transceiver: internal
Auto-negotiation: on
MDI-X: Unknown
Supports Wake-on: pumbg
Wake-on: g
Current message level: 0x00000033 (51)
               drv probe ifdown ifup
Link detected: no
```

Answer (score 0):

Install another driver by the vendor. Run

```
sudo apt install r8168-dkms
```

and reboot.

Comment: This didn't worked. Still same. After wire connected shows message about wire connection. After few seconds- wire disconnected

Comment: Check cable, plugs, etc. This NIC works well with the vendor driver.

Comment: With windows works everything good. I think problem is with network-manager

Comment: Very unlikely that the problem is with NM. Bit it is very easy to find out. Connect without NM.

Comment: Tell me more how to do this

Comment: You can setup a connection in `/etc/network/interfaces`. You can search the Net for more details. But I do not think it will help.

Comment: Done that. Result is in Update #1